# Redirecting from block not working

Tags: redirect, magento2.1.5, redirection

I'm trying to redirect from block but it's not working. But same methods work in different projects.

**1. Process 1**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\PaymentGateway\Helper\Data $storeHelper,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,      
    \Vendor\PaymentGateway\Model\CreateorderFactory $createorder,
    \Vendor\PaymentGateway\Model\PaymentresponseFactory $paymentResponse,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderEmailSender,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->storeHelper  = $storeHelper;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->response = $response;
    $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
    $this->createorder = $createorder;
    $this->paymentResponse = $paymentResponse;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->orderEmailSender = $orderEmailSender;
    $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
}
public function redirectAccordingToStatus($status='30')
{
    echo 'redirect from here  ' , $this->getBaseUrl().$this->REDIRECT_URL[$status] ;
    //return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath($this->REDIRECT_URL[$status]);
    $this->response->setRedirect($this->getBaseUrl().$this->REDIRECT_URL[$status]);
    exit;
}
```

**2. Process 2: With same constructor but different approach.**

```
return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath('paym/payment/cancel');
```

None of these methods are working. I thought some of the classes could be conflicting with it that is why I have pasted the whole code of constructor.

Also there is no error during `setup:di:compile` and in logs. If you know of any another approach then please suggest that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,

    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $context->getUrlBuilder();;
    }
```

USE LIKE THIS::

```
  $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
                $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
```

Comment: Man it's working, but I got error in compilation. So would you help me with that as well. `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface already exists in context object`

Comment: I've fixed the error with edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the **Process 2**, with a slight change.

You have to use `ResultFactory` instead of `RedirectFactory` and you have to specify the type as redirect, so your code should be changed to

```
public function __construct(
    ................
    .......................
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    ........
    ..........
    $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
}
public function redirectAccordingToStatus($status='30')
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('paym/payment/cancel');
}
```

Run the setup upgrade again and check if it's working.

Comment: I tried , not working. I don't understan why, this is not working.